# replace fixed position data using SED

Tags: shell, unix

I have data `FHEAD0000000001STKU201508192259592015081700000000000000S00031101200` in a file .

1. Now i need to replace 56th char with some `:X` value which i will derive. Here lets say `:x ='S'` using SED command.
2. I need to replace from 48th char to 55th char with `:Y =1234` and if `:Y =4` char then rest of zeros's should be present in the line.

Please help me to achieve this using SED in unix.

Expected output:

The expected output for questions:

1. `FHEAD0000000001STKU201508192259592015081700000000000000S00031101200` as on 56th char already 'S' present so no difference in output.
2. `FHEAD0000000001STKU201508192259592015081700000000001234S00031101200` here i have replaced 1234 and rest of zeros are present

Comment: Could you please provide a sample output?

Comment: You need to provide your expected output for the given input string.

Comment: The expected output for question (i) FHEAD0000000001STKU201508192259592015081700000000000000S00031101200 as on 56th char already 'S' present so no difference in output. (ii) FHEAD0000000001STKU201508192259592015081700000000001234S00031101200  here i have replaced 1234 and rest of zeros present.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] together with what you tried. The first case is a bit dummy, since you already have S in the 56th position, the second case is a bit weird.